# How Can i get rid of this large lib files

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, shared-libraries, android-design-library

[image]

Please anyone help me in my project this files got entered with large size so how to get rid of this. and in other project this file aren't their

Comment: Import only needed libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are libs for specific architectures. If you deliver your app using app bundle it shouldn't be a problem since app bundle will only deliver the necessary for each architecture (so the build will use less disk space).

But if want you want is offer your app to a limited abi list you can use this in your build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            abiFilters 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

check this for more abi info https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis